# How can I configure the LDAP query template in Evolution?

Tags: evolution

I am using Evolution to query the address book of a large LDAP server. I am receiving responses, but the actual search target is not contained in them. I have checked using an LDAP library that I can obtain these entries from the server. However, I have also found in the documentation that the server will only answer certain queries to avoid load issues.

I am assuming that Evolution uses an LDAP query template with a wildcard,
and I would like to change that template to fit the requirements of the server so I can obtain the right responses.

My question: Is the Evolution LDAP query format configurable and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I believe (but I cannot test right now) that you can use the format as supported by `ldapsearch()`.

Right-click your LDAP addressbook, click 'properties' and add your filter into the form, f.e.

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(name=*))
```

HTH.